# Rebuses are so cliché

Tags: visual, rebus

Here's a good puzzle to end the day with.  See if you can figure out what the image sequence is telling you.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

## Hints:

## 1

> The first picture has to do with the 24th nickname, though it's not official, or anything.

## 2

> The third image refers to a place - but not a specific place.

Comment: Technically speaking this phrase is not required to be gender-specific, but for the case of this puzzle, please pretend that it is.

Comment: Gotta say, the layout's color and shape transitions *solve* some puzzles familiar to artists

Comment: Does it have to do with rot13(Znafpncvat)? Hahaha.

Comment: I had to decode that twice, to make sure I hadn't screwed up.  Hahaha, no :P

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I don't understand your comment about gender specificity.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Wait, I think I get it now. Are you saying it would be possible to make a rebus for a version this phrase without using the NO WOMAN sign?

Comment: @question_asker I just mean that the cliché could be specified with a different middle word, but in the case of the puzzle, I'm requiring a specific one.

Comment: No correct answers as of the time of this posting.  Great tries, guys!  Some hints:  The first picture is less about the arch and more about where that arch can be found.  The third picture is something more general - something great.

Comment: I keep thinking rot13(Nepuqhxr) but can't fit the last picture. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: My sure you read my comment, above yours :) @Z.Dailey

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I know. And I've messed with that too.

Comment: Dang about the comment concerning the usage of gender. I really liked my theory that that particular image meant "now" (No W).

Comment: @Z.Dailey I used a word from KK's comment to guess at the last word, but I know of exactly zero (0) idioms that use that word (other than the one you make using the word from the comment, that is)

Comment: I've been trying to think up some hints for this one.  I'll see if I can post some, later, if it hasn't been solved.

Comment: I for one would love to see a dang ol hint

Comment: Let's see if those help.

Comment: Gotta love the unexplained downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first picture is

> The St. Louis Arch, in Missouri, the **Show**-Me State

The second picture is

> Not her, but **him**

The third picture is

> The great outdoors, or simply **out**

The rebus could be

> **Show him out** (i.e., point a man toward the door, so that he leaves)

Comment: Nice =D.  This puzzle was less transparent than I originally hoped.  Oops.

Answer (score 5):

My theory:

> Overarching his view.

Breakdown:

> Overarching: an arch over, his: not a woman, view: a picture of a spectacular vista.

Comment: A decent guess, but I can't say I've ever heard anyone say it, before.

Answer (score 4):

The path underneath this beautiful blue arch is not accessible for women.

Comment: Haha, nice try =D

Answer (score 2):

> **Archman** is a town in south-western Turkmenistan. **Archman** lies in the Ahal Province on the northern rim of the Kopet Dag mountain range.
>  The first picture shows an **arch**. 
>  The second picture shows not a woman meaning **man** 
>  The third picturen shows a picture of the suroundings of town **Archman**

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> The Bob Marley song: No Woman, No Cry

because

> Missouri = Misery
>  No Woman
>  Heaven/Paradise

Comment: The song to which you are referring is actually "No Woman, Nuh Cry", which is an address to a woman urging her to not cry. "no, woman: don't cry".

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've never seen it as "nuh"

Comment: @question_asker It is not written as "nuh"; it is said as "nuh". You are free to use google.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oh, no, I just thought you were miscorrecting them on the title.

Comment: @question_asker Just on the meaning behind the title; the explanation doesn't fit when the title is interpreted correctly.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's fair! Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> The gateway to no-(wo)man's land

Explanation:

> The Arch is sometimes called the gateway to the west. 
>  The second picture was listed as gender unspecific, but was looking for a gender specific answer. 
>  The third picture was hinted at being a simple answer 
>  Possible coincidence, but there's a startrek GATEWAYs book called NO MANS LAND.

Worth a shot.

Comment: Nice try, though this one made me laugh.  Let's see if I can add a hint =D

Comment: Haha. Yah. It needs a small one. I'm sure if you make a simple one it'll be enough to point people in the right direction. @Khale_Kitha

Answer (score 1):

> City Women Rock (it's not rocket science)